# micromax a67 mobile strucks at no command mode, how to do a factory reset in command mode

Tags: android, operating-system

my micromax a67 phone is having some problem it dosen't start, structs at no command mode and factory reset setting options is not coming.  what to do to perform a factory reset when phone not  even starting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just hold the power and volume down button, it will open a command mode in screen to reset the phone.

Comment: This should be a comment

Comment: Command mode actually not coming, there is Android robot with error, no command mode after that nothing works